# Sqlite query troble

Tags: database, sqlite

i am doing android project by using sqlite db ,in select query i have error that is cursor bound exception (0) ,my query is :

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM COMPDETAIL WHERE city='Bangalore' AND service='Hospital';");
```

by replacing AND by OR it working..

what am I suppose to do, if I want COMPDETAIL by multiple conditions...

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

use moveToFirst():

```
if (c != null) { 
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure such row (with city = 'Bangalore' and service = 'Hospital') exists in your database? `AND` is [perfectly legal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) keyword in SQLite, there's no reason it wouldn't work and `OR` would... unless, there's no row matching both criteria, and you still try to fetch it - which will produce something along the lines of *out of bounds* exception.